# Generate new deposit address in Binance

Tags: rest, blockchain, binance, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

We want to create a crypto exchange website by using Binance API for sending and receiving crypto assets. But the problem is that we cannot generate unique addresses per user per coin and all the users are sending theirs assets into the same deposit address.

How can we generate new deposit address per user per coin ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Did you found out if is it possible and how? I'm running into the same situation

Comment: I'm running into the same situation

Comment: @AmedeAngelAulerien it is not possible in personal accounts maybe it is available in corporate accounts

Comment: it is not possible in personal accounts maybe it is available in corporate accounts